# Return a "mmm-yy" value from an acecss query

Tags: ms-access

I writing a query where i need to return a set of data, one of which needs to be a date in the format mmm-yy.

I am currently using *Format(DateValue([CCContactDate]),"mmm-yy")* however this shows in Excel as Apr-17 but the value in the cell is still 02/04/2017 and i need to report by month and year.

Is there a way to amend the query to just return Apr-17?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MonthName(Month(ccdate)) & "-" & Year(ccDate)`